# Ionic v3 One Signal notificacions - How to switch on/off notifications

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

I'm using one signal notifications with ionic v3 and they're working perfectly. What would be the correct way to activate/deactivate notifications from the app? Im lost here.
I search about this and i have this code:

page.html

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="OSnotificaciones" (ionChange)="cambiarNotificacion()" checked="true" ></ion-toggle>
```

page.ts

```
OSnotificaciones: boolean = false;
cambiarNotificacion() {
if(this.OSnotificaciones == true){
  window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription(false);  
} else {
  window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this :

```js
cambiarNotificacion() {
  window["plugins"].OneSignal.setSubscription(this.OSnotificaciones);
```

Let me know if it works !

EDIT : I did not see before that it was a reverse boolean in your condition, try the new code :

```js
cambiarNotificacion() {
  window["plugins"].OneSignal.setSubscription(!this.OSnotificaciones);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... the editor show me this error:
Property 'plugins' does not exist on type 'Window'. Any idea why?

Comment: Well, i change this window.plugins for this window['plugins'] and i dont have any error... Now I'm going to test if the code does what it has to do... this code works for you? i mean, switch the notifications?

Comment: works great! but i never get the actual user status of the notification...i dont find the event to get that info.

Comment: Nice if it works, is it an issue with this code ? I have updated my answer with your change too

Comment: Thanks again, I'm going to create another publication with that new issue so as not to confuse.